# Dúvida sobre atributos inicializados no construtor no Java

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, encapsulamento

```java
package Livraria3;

public class Livro {

    private String nome;
    private String descricao;
    private double valor;
    private String isbn;
    Autor autor;

    public Livro(Autor autor) {
        this.autor = autor;
        this.isbn = "000-00-00000-00-0";

    }

    public Livro() {

    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }
    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }
    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }
    public double getValor() {
        return valor;
    }
    public void setValor(double valor) {
        this.valor = valor;
    }
    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }
    public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }
    public Autor getAutor() {
        return autor;
    }
    public void setAutor(Autor autor) {
        this.autor = autor;
    }

    public void mostrarDetalhes() {

           System.out.println("Mostrando detalhes do livro:");
           System.out.println("Nome: " + nome);
           System.out.println("Descricao: " + descricao);
           System.out.println("Valor: " + valor);
           System.out.println("Isbn: " + isbn);
           System.out.println("--");

           autor.mostrarDetalhes();

        }


}
```

```java
 package Livraria3;

    public class Autor {

        private String nome;
        private String email;
        private String cpf;

        public String getNome() {
            return nome;
        }
        public void setNome(String nome) {
            this.nome = nome;
        }
        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }
        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }
        public String getCpf() {
            return cpf;
        }
        public void setCpf(String cpf) {
            this.cpf = cpf;
        }

        public void mostrarDetalhes() {

              System.out.println("Mostrando detalhes do Autor:");
              System.out.println("Nome: " + nome);
              System.out.println("Email: " + email);
              System.out.println("CPF: " + cpf);

              }
    }
```

```java
package Livraria3;

public class CadastroDeLivros {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Autor autor = new Autor();
        autor.setNome("Leonardo Silva");
        autor.setEmail("leonardo_silva@hotmail.com");
        autor.setCpf("231.980.523.66");

        Livro livro = new Livro(autor);
        livro.setNome("Programacao em Java");
        livro.setDescricao("Livro de Java");
        livro.setValor(79.90);


        //livro.setAutor(autor);
        livro.mostrarDetalhes();


        Autor outroAutor = new Autor();
        outroAutor.setNome("Tiago Vieira");
        outroAutor.setEmail("tiagov@yahoo.com");
        outroAutor.setCpf("331-453-234-75");

        Livro outroLivro = new Livro(outroAutor);
        outroLivro.setNome("Programacao em Cpp");
        outroLivro.setDescricao("Livro de cpp");
        outroLivro.setValor(89.90);
        outroLivro.setIsbn("459-94-9103-15-34");

        //outroLivro.setAutor(outroAutor);
        outroLivro.mostrarDetalhes();

}
}
```

Tem alguma diferença de eu inicializar um atributo de um objeto no construtor da classe, como:

```java
public Livro(Autor autor) {
        this.autor = autor;
        this.isbn = "000-00-00000-00-0";
        this.valor = 66.66;
    }
```

Ou usar aqui?

```java
Livro livro = new Livro(autor);
        livro.setNome("Programacao em Java");
        livro.setDescricao("Livro de Java");
        livro.setValor(79.90);
      //livro.isb = "567-67-667-66-77;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Tem alguma diferença de eu iniciar um atributo de um objeto no
>   construtor da classe?

Sim, ao expor apenas um construtor, com os atributos da classe que você deseja criar, você pode forcar aqueles que chamam seu construtor a passar todos os parametros necessários para criacão do objeto. Enquanto que se você usar `Setters`, Alguém pode não chamar os setters necessários para que o objeto esteja em um estado válido. Essa seria uma das principais diferencas. Existe até mesmo uma exceção em Java para quando seu objeto não está em um estado válido:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalStateException.html

Agora, se é certo ou errado, ou que é melhor, é difícil dizer pois depende muito do design do seu programa, ou de sua API.

Comment: Desculpe, mas eu não sei ler a API.

Comment: Oi @Nome, vc se refere a pagina em ingles, ou ao termo API?

Comment: Muito técnico, não por ser em inglês.

Comment: Com o tempo vc se acostuma. É só ir praticando. =)

Answer (score 1):

Os dois vão funcionar, mas existem diferenças estruturais importantes.

Ao inicializar tudo no construtor, é mais fácil de garantir o encapsulamento, pois você não é obrigado a publicar setters.

Além disso, você garante que o objeto será criado em um estado que faça sentido. Do contrário, você provavelmente vai criar um objeto em um estado incoerente e ser obrigado a consertá-lo depois, o que é ruim.

Comment: O.0 mais fácil manutenção.

Comment: @Nome Exato, a manutenção fica mais fácil. O seu objeto fica mais fácil de ser usado da forma correta e mais difícil de ser usado da forma errada.