# Dúvida sobre como utilizar Hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

Estou com uma dúvida sobre o uso do `Hashmap` do Java. Nessa ocasião, eu tenho uma classe com o atributo `Hashmap custo`.

Nessa classe, preciso criar um construtor e nesse construtor, preciso solicitar a inserção de 3 inteiros que irão compor esse meu custo (ouro, madeira e diamante).

Minha dúvida é: como eu faço para solicitar esses 3 dados a fim de preenchê-los em meu custo? E como eu faço para exibir e utilizar os mesmos posteriormente?

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/72885/28595

Comment: Solicitar significa pedir que o usuário digite a informação. Se não foi explicada a entrada, então assuma que é da entrada padrão (normalmente o teclado). Se seu problema for esse, você não tem problemas com o `HashMap` mas sim com interação com usuário

Comment: Eu preciso fazer com que ele digite essas 3 informações e eu preciso armazená-las, contudo, não sei como fazer isso utilizando o HashMap.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Creio que seja isso que queira.

Abraços

```
    //CRIANDO O MAP CUSTO
    HashMap<String, Integer> custo = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    //PEDINDO A INFORMAÇÃO PARA O USUÁRIO
    System.out.println("DIGITE A QUANTIDADE DE OURO");
    Scanner readOuro = new Scanner(System.in);

    //OBTENDO A INFORMAÇÃO DO TECLADO
    Integer qtdOuro = readOuro.nextInt();

    //INSERINDO A QUANTIDADE DE OURO AO MAPA COM A CHAVE OURO
    custo.put("OURO", qtdOuro);


    //FAZENDO A MESMA COISA PARA MADEIRA E DIAMANTE

    System.out.println("DIGITE A QUANTIDADE DE MADEIRA");
    Scanner readMadeira = new Scanner(System.in);
    Integer qtdMadeira = readMadeira.nextInt();
    custo.put("MADEIRA", qtdMadeira);




    System.out.println("DIGITE A QUANTIDADE DE DIAMANTE");
    Scanner readDiamante = new Scanner(System.in);
    Integer qtdDiamante = readDiamante.nextInt();
    custo.put("DIAMANTE", qtdDiamante);
```

Comment: Perfeito! Eu só consigo passar 2 informações por vez ou posso criar apenas um put pra passar todas de uma vez só? Lhe peço isso pois a minha ideia é inserir tudo diretamente no construtor que criarei dessa classe.

Comment: O HasMap é Chave, Valor. Tendo isso em mente você pode modelar seu problema de várias formas, essa foi a mais intuitiva que achei para lhe mostrar...

Comment: Me ajudou muito já! Obrigado mesmo. Grande abraço! :D